# Intercept paste action in a UIWebView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Is there a way in Swift to get the pasted content before it is pasted? Ideally I should be to read the to be pasted content when user selects 'paste' from the default pop-up menu in an editable element. Right now I'm looking at a UIWebView with the a content editable div.

Code I have so far (inspired by Ludovic's answer)

```
class myWebView: UIWebView {

        override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        print(action)

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }

}
```

Output (every time I tap on the content editable div):

cut:
copy:
select:
selectAll:
delete:
_promptForReplace:
_transliterateChinese:
_showTextStyleOptions:
_lookup:
_define:
_addShortcut:
_accessibilitySpeak:
_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
_share:
makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:

Eventhough paste selector is not listed here it is available in the popup menu.

Comment: I think you can just read and show it before the user do anything, similar to some browser app, not sure about intercepting the action, maybe intercept the textfield text appearing is better idea

Comment: You mean pasting content in `UITextField` or `UITextView`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the pasted content before it paste as

```
let pasteboardString: String? = UIPasteboard.general.string
if let theString = pasteboardString {
    print("String is \(theString)")
}
```

Comment: I think this will only show a string that has been copy to the UIPasteboard but will not be trigger before user touch "paste".

Comment: You mean pasting content in UITextField or UITextView?

Answer (score 1):

**Objective C**

```
CLS_LOG(@"copied test %@",[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string]);
```

**Swift**

```
print("String is \(UIPasteboard.general.string)")
```

Comment: where should I place this code? When would I know that the general pasteboard has copied content?

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `canPerformAction` method to catch action

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
        // Do something
        return false // Will disable paste action
    }

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)  
}
```

You can extend all UITextField to have this feature everywhere in your app or create a custom CatchPasteTextField to have this feature only for a given UITextField class

Comment: thanks for this. Please see the updated question. Doesn't seem to work still. Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm looking at an UIWebView.

Comment: I never try but this should work with UIWebView to. Extend UIWebView instead of UITextField